# Generating text based on selected option in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, text, html-select

I am trying to create a site where you select an option from a dropdown list called *contactOptions*. The options has values ranging from 0 to 8. When the option is selected, I wish for text to appear underneath -- this text is contained within div tags with ID's such as *#contact0* for the text corresponding to option 0. These ID's all have *display: none* by default. I have some JavaScript (below) -- the select tag in my html includes the line *onchange = "sortForm()"*. Unfortunately, the script does not do anything -- the *#contact0* remains invisible.

```
function sortForm() {
  var selection = document.getElementById("contactOptions");
  var selectedValue = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value;

  for (var i = 0; i <=8; i++) {
    var subobjContact = document.getElementById("contact" + i);
    if (i == selectedValue) {
      subobjContact.style.display == "block"
    } else {
      subobjContact.style.display == "none"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single equal sign

```
subobjContact.style.display = "block"
```

and

```
subobjContact.style.display = "none"
```

Comment: I'll accept that as soon as I can, need to wait 8 mins. Thank you -- so annoying when you comb the code and it turns out to be something so stupid like that. *cry*